# Can the human gut work with other type of gut bacteria?

Tags: bacteriology, digestive-system, digestion, gut-bacteria

I was wondering if the human body would be capable of functioning with, say, cellulolytic bacteria in their gut (instead of or in addition of their current bacteria), like that of ruminants and if they'd be able to digest cellulose thanks to it.

Couldn't find any papers on that, only on the implantation of faecal matter from a healthy gut to a sick one, nothing interspecific.

Comment: interspecies transfer of fecal material occurs often enough, but we usually study it in terms of pathogens and parasite life cycles. Interesting question. Probably tough to get IRB approval for that one, though.

Comment: @DanHall hahaha, bet. It'd definitely be interesting though! I'd like to hear the point of view of someone who's done human-human faecal transfers and what they think would happen!